# How can I make a specific row unselectable in a Vaadin Grid with a mult-selection model?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I'm trying to disable the checkbox on a specific row based on some property of it's Bean (or just make the whole row generally unselectable), but I can't really see any method or property I could use to get a handle of the checkboxes on the left hand side added when using a multi-selection model or something as broad as disabling the whole row. Any thoughts on how this could be achieved, or where I should be looking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide uncheckable rows. First set their styles using `setRowStyleGenerator`:

```
grid.setRowStyleGenerator(row -> {
    boolean uncheckable = (Boolean) 
        row.getItem().getItemProperty("uncheckable").getValue();
    return uncheckable ? "uncheckable-row" : "";
});
```

Then change styles in your .scss, they should look something like:

```
.v-grid-row.uncheckable-row td {
    background: #b1b9d6 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.v-grid-row.uncheckable-row td:first-child {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.v-grid-row.uncheckable-row.v-grid-row-selected > .v-grid-cell {
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #d4d4d4;
    color: inherit;
    text-shadow: inherit;
}
```

Here I hide the whole cell with checkbox (if hiding the content of `td` itself, user will still be available to select the row), use a different color for these rows and prevent them from being highlighted when "select all" checkbox is active. Surely, further styling is available. Since we only hide them from user, they still can be selected with `grid.select()` and located in `grid.getSelectedRows()` collection, you should filter them manually (by using some "uncheckable" property, as shown above).

Comment: Thanks @jqrsd, that looks like just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to disable checkbox on a specific row.

One solution is to use generated column and/or custom renderer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using twitter bootstrap as your responsive framework, you should be able to find that row and give it a class of ".inactive", and if that doesn't work you can always rig it but placing and absolute positioned box with a height and width of 100% inside of that row and z-index it to at least 250.  That should make everything  in that row un-clickable!